# How do I use local-font in a react-vite environment?

Tags: reactjs, fonts, vite

**directory**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNKfJ.jpg)

**css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Pretendard";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("@/assets/fonts/Pretendard-Regular") format("woff");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Pretendard";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("@/assets/fonts/Pretendard-Medium") format("woff");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Pretendard";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("@/assets/fonts/Pretendard-SemiBold") format("woff");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Pretendard";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("@/assets/fonts/Pretendard-Bold") format("woff");
}

* {
  font-family: "Pretendard", sans-serif;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGzG1.jpg)

**main.jsx**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "@/App.jsx";
import "@/assets/fonts/font.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdmq9.jpg)

**Q**

How can I use the fonts I have locally?
I want to apply that font as the default font. Please explain in detail.

Comment: What you have should work. If it doesn't, it means you are loading another CSS rule which overrides the `font-family`, applied by a selector of higher specificity or by a selector of equal specificity which is applied later.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge, you need to include the extension of your fonts

> Without the correct file extension, several issues may arise: failure
> to load, Compatibility issue, dependency configuration, etc

- fonts.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Pretendard";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("@/assets/fonts/Pretendard-Regular.woff") format("woff"); 
}
.....

// also applied to global
* {
  font-family: "Pretendard", sans-serif;
}
```

then you import it to your styles to your `main.jsx`